# Can you use the annotation free wcf with SOAP?

Tags: wcf, soap

I want to use the newer Wcf (Data services unique?) `poco`s which don't need any annotations for their types. Can this done with `SOAP`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as of .NET 3.5 SP1, you don't *have to* use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on your data classes anymore; and this applies to **all** shapes and styles of WCF. If you omit those attributes entirely, WCF will treat the class like the XML serializer (use/serialize all public properties).

**HOWEVER:** by doing this you're giving up a lot of flexibility:

- you **cannot** define a XML namespace for your data contracts
- you **cannot** exclude a public property from serialization by omitting the `[DataMember]` on it.......
- you **cannot** define an order for the properties to be used in the serialized XML anymore
- and more.....

Comment: Is this the same method/system that requires ID to be on the primary key(s)? Thanks, Can you provide detail on the "more..." ?

Comment: @Maslow: well, there's also an `IsRequired` option on `[DataMember]` which of course you cannot use if you omit that attribute; furthermore, with the `Name=` value you are able to rename a property to be serialized under a different name - and of course, you cannot use that feature, either, if you omit the `[DataMember]` .....

Comment: @Maslow: no, this has absolutely **nothing** to do with database-related primary key issues / conventions .... WCF has no knowledge of databases at all

Comment: What is it that requires the ID suffix on primary keys to function? I had to do that with Wcf Data services for it to hook up properly as I recall.

Comment: @Maslow: again, that has **NOTHING** to do with WCF - that must be something else (and with WCF Data Services, you *most likely* have an Entity Framework model in play -> that's the more likely suspect)